# I wanted to take datas from database and also change the query dynamically and store the id from database in an array and use then to call a function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am new to PHP, can anyone help me out in this. What I am trying to do is call a function which fetch id from a table and store id in an array, then calling another method in a loop in such a way that the array elements should be parameter which is passing in function.

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$releaseidarr=array();

function getreleaseid($p)
{
    $releaseid=array();
    $releaseidp="select release_id from `release` where project_id=".$p.";";
    $query4=mysql_query($GLOBALS['db'],$releaseidp);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query4))
    {
        $releaseid[]=$row['release_id'];
    }
    return $releaseid;

}
$p=1;
while($p<8)
{
    //echo "hi";
    $releaseidarr=getreleaseid($p);
    echo $releaseidarr[$p];
    $p++;
}

?>

Connection.php contains

<?php

$GLOBALS['server']="******";
$GLOBALS['username']="*****";
$GLOBALS['password']="****";
$GLOBALS['database']="dashtest";

$GLOBALS['conn']= mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";    

$GLOBALS['db'] = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
//echo "connected";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Don't use both mysql and mysqli. Only use to write in mysqli. 
and in foreach loop use array push method. first declare one empty array like

```
$array = [];
foreach($a as $k){
array_push($array,$k);
}
return $array;
```